# Using constexpr as a rvalue

Tags: c++, constexpr

Is there a way to use constexpr without the need to create an extra variable? Take for example the code below, which maps a type to a global object. The why of the mapping should not be relevant to the question.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct S { int val; };

S one{1};
S two{2};

template<typename>
constexpr S& get() = delete;

template<>
constexpr S& get<int>() { return one; };

template<>
constexpr S& get<double>() { return two; };

auto main() -> int {

    constexpr auto& type = get<int>();

    std::cout << type.val << std::endl;
    std::cout << get<double>().val << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7hcjrob39)

The call to `get<double>();` does not get treated as a `constexpr`, and it's executed at runtime (with, optimizations the call is inlined and it's equivalent to `constexpr`). The call to `constexpr auto& type = get<int>();` does make use of `constexpr` do requires another variable. Just for usability, is there something to this extent `std::cout << (constexpr get<int>()) << std::endl;` that could be used?

Comment: C++20's `consteval`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Too bad I'm stuck with c++14.

Comment: "with, optimizations the call is inlined and it's equivalent to constexpr" why is that not ok?

Comment: there are ways to enforce compile time evaluation also in c++14. You could write a class template with `val` as `static` member, but thats possibly a step back compared to what you have

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is, I just wanted more consistency if that makes sense.

Comment: `constexpr` only implies that `get` can be evaluated at compile time. It does not imply that it is always evaluated at compile time. If you assume the latter then there is inconsistency. Whether it is called at compile time in contexts where it can be called at runtime, the compiler still decides as it does without `constexpr`